# Should I use wp_reset_postdata() or just save the global $post variable myself?

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress 4.3 site that uses Yoast for SEO. I have a custom post type and a shortcode that can be used to generate a list of posts of that type. The shortcode function uses what I believe to be the [recommended approach](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) in Wordpress for generating a list of posts of a certain type:

```
$query = new WP_Query(...);

while ($query->have_posts())
{
    $query->the_post();
    // Now I can call methods like the_ID(), the_permalink(), etc
    // I can also access details of the post directly, because at
    // this point it is stored in the global $post variable.
}

wp_reset_postdata(); // To restore original copy of global $post variable
```

When viewing the actual page that contains the shortcode, everything works fine because the global `$wp_query` variable stashes a copy of the global `$post` variable before the shortcode function gets called, which enables `wp_reset_postdata()` to successfully restore the state of the global `$post` variable.

However, I recently discovered a problem when *editing* the page and although I have fixed the issue, I would like to know if my solution is correct practice in the Wordpress world.

The problem was that whenever I edited the page, several fields would get changed without me having actually touched any of the settings. Further investigation revealed that the reason for this was that the HTML for the edit page, specifically the contents of some form fields, **had already been altered** by the time they reached my browser. Compounding this problem was the fact that the permalink field, which is highly visible, was not being altered, but a hidden field called `slug` **was** being altered, and so when the page was submitted, Wordpress was updating the permalink with the value of this now corrupted, hidden slug field. My permalink wasn't so perma after all!

The only clue I had about what was causing the problem was that the permalink that was being set belonged to another post; in fact, one of the posts that comes up when the shortcode function gets executed.

After a day and a half of debugging, I figured out the precise reason why the form fields were being trashed:

1. When preparing the edit page for a post, Wordpress calls all the related plugins in case they need to add any additional information or controls to the sidebar.
2. One such plugin is Yoast, which reports an SEO Status. In order to calculate this status, Yoast silently renders the post so that it can then analyse the contents of the page, taking into account the focus keywords, etc.
3. In order for Yoast to silently render a page, all of the shortcode functions that contribute output to that page must also be executed.
4. When my shortcode function gets executed as part of Yoast's silent page rendering, it does what I beleive to be the right thing by calling `wp_reset_postdata()` at the end to restore the contents of the global `$post` variable.

However, the problem was that `wp_reset_postdata()` was not, in fact, restoring the global `$post` variable, because the global `$wp_query` variable did not have a copy. I would have expected `wp_reset_postdata()` or `WP_Query->reset_postdata()` to throw an error at that point, but they don't.

So every form field in the edit page that was generated after Yoast did its work ended up with values from the wrong post, because the global `$post` variable had been left with the wrong contents.

I have resolved the problem by adding the following defensive/unobtrusive code to the top of my shortcode function:

```
global $wp_query;

if ( $wp_query->post == null )
{
    return '';
}
```

This means my shortcode function will only execute "the loop" when there is a guarantee that it will be able to restore the global `$post` variable using `wp_reset_postdata()`.

Should I stick to this solution or take it one step further and simply save a copy of the global `$post` variable myself and just ignore `wp_reset_postdata()` altogether?

Comment: Does the main query object get altered in anyway throughout the page. Do a `var_dump( $wp_query );` before and after every query and compare the results. This should not differ in any way. If it does, something is using `query_posts` which will explain the behavior you are seeing. Try to also call `wp_reset_query()` before you start a new query and check the results. If your results are correct after applying `wp_reset_query()`, then something is definitely altering the main query object, and in all probability, it is `query_posts`

Comment: Thanks for your question Pieter. Unfortunately both `$GLOBALS['wp_query']` and `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']` are essentially blank before my shortcode function gets run when editing the page (eg. http://pastebin.com/7eVUNGPg). So calling `wp_reset_query()` has no effect, since that function simply replaces  `$GLOBALS['wp_query']` with `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']`, which does not have a copy of `$GLOBALS['post']` either, which is what has been overwritten. From what I can tell, both of these variables are only populated when a page is being viewed, not when a page is being edited.